# How to Upload File on Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I'm developing an ASP.NET web app using VS2010,C#.

I want to display a file upload control when my users click on an hyperlink and then the upload operation should be performed.

I have an invisible upload control which display it using JavaScript in my hyperlink `onclick` event handler, the upload control is displayed but I don't know how the get the uploaded file, how should I perform this operation?

I want to display upload file dialog when my users click on a label or hyperlink, then they can select their file and the file should be uploaded and saved into the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need another button (maybe with name 'Upload'), to perform this operation. When you choose a file using a File uploader control you need to click on the 'Upload' button. Write C# code to save your chosen file on button click event.

Save your file by using the following code:

```
Fileuploadercontrol.saveAs('//path here');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div>
 <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</div>
```

In C# put this :

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi sfk. I know this code but i want to upload images like a yahoo or gmail Attach Files. They upload files on Hyperlink.